# React Native | How npm Dependencies affect the AAB (Android App Bundle) release Size

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am new to React-Native and Node.js in general coming from a Python background I don't
understand how dependencies are handled in React-Native (but probably is how it works in node.js too).

### Question

***When buillding a React Native AAB, do all Node Module declared in `node_modules directory been built / included into the` AAB` or only the one that I actually use?***

***I yes, How can I choose which modules to include (maybe in the `build.gradle` file), I am very tented to just delete modules manually if there is not a solution***

---

### Issue

In a React-Native App build with `react-native init [proj_name]` command the folder `node_modules` is created in the directory. I've installed locally `react-native/navigation. react-native/stack` & `react-native-fast-storage`. For my understanding, those aren't many externa dependency for a Ract-Native App.

The folder takes about 230 MB, I understand that the most was created when running `react-native init [proj_name]`. (despite the final App is 40.78 MB) they may be at least 100-200 modules folders.

It seems a waste of modules declared and I don't understand whether they are all included or not in the final built despite I use only few of those.

In `build.gradle` these 2 are enabled, ( I add this in case someone comes up with this, despite is not what I am asking):

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```

---

### Documentation followed to build AAB

- [Publishing to Google Play Store - React Native DOCS -](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android)

Answer (score 0):

after creating the `abb file` you can delete the `node modules`. In react-native, only those modules are added in the `abb file` that is actually used.

after deleting the node modules if you need again to run your project just do the following command `npm install` and it will install the node modules again.

Comment: is not really what I asked. I don't mind to have many node modules on the Development project. I asked if, during ABB file creation, all node modules are included into the ABB file whether in the App are used or not.  And consequently how to tell  (like in the gradle file) which node modules to pick up and which to leave

Comment: Basicallly like a .gitignore but for creating the AAB file